# Set the mark at the beginning of the current function definition

Tags: debugging, mark

I want this function: assume that I am inside a function, and in line 100, now I want to go to the definition of this function, say 80, and set mark, then go back to 100. So now I have an active region between 80 and 100. I write this function like this:

```
(defun my-select-fun ()
  (interactive)
  (setq myline 'line-number-at-pos ) 
  (beginning-of-defun)
  (set-mark)
  (goto-line myline)
)
```

But it is not working, and I get an error: `Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 0`. Sorry for not be familiar with emacs lisp, could someone help me to implement this simple function? Thank you very much.

Comment: `line-number-at-pos` is a function, you should use `(line-number-at-pos)`.

Comment: The title of your question should be more indicative.

Comment: You should report the full error message, which no doubt told you which function was passed the wrong number of arguments (`set-mark` requires a position argument).

Answer (score 2):

The function set-mark takes an argument, POS, and you didn't supply one.  That's why you're getting the error.
Have a look at the docs for set-mark (using C-h f set-mark).  You probably want (push-mark (point)) instead.

Comment: `push-mark ` does not work like I expected. Anyway, I still use `set-mark`, which solved this problem. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

As jeffkowalski mentioned, you have to pass the position as an argument. And I think you can't use `set-mark` for this.

```
(defun my-select-fun (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((myline (line-number-at-pos))))
    (beginning-of-defun)
    (set-mark-command arg)
    (goto-line myline)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is arg? I don't want any arguments. Thank you though.

Comment: arg in combination with (interactive "p") provides the cursor's point just like `(point)`, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem:

```
(defun my-select-fun ()
  (interactive)
  (setq myline (line-number-at-pos))
  (beginning-of-defun)
  (set-mark (point))
  (goto-line myline)
)
```

Thanks to other answers though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you really want is to *select the defun that is around point*. `C-M-h` (command `mark-defun`) does that.

If you really want to return to the original position then just write a command that binds a variable to `(point)` at the outset, then calls `mark-defun`, then uses `goto-char` to return to the position saved in that variable.  To prevent the region from becoming deactivated after using your command, end it with `(setq deactivate-mark  nil)`.